# Comparing strings gives wrong results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am letting users type in a word or a sentence in an `input` and this will be compared to other strings. Then I run a `.each` on each string result to see if there is a matching string and if so continue other wise remove some elements:

```js
var text2;
var text2B;
text2 = jQuery('#usp-title').val();
text2B = text2.toLowerCase();
jQuery("#datafetch").html(data).promise().done(function() {
  jQuery("#datafetch ul li h2 a").each(function() {
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    if ($this.text().toLowerCase().trim() !== text2B.trim()) {
      $this.parent().parent().remove();
      jQuery(".jumbotron").remove();
      jQuery("#componi").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="#usp-title" type="text">
```

But `jQuery(".jumbotron").remove();` is happening anyway. I know it because all the results have been removed with `$this.parent().parent().remove();` and I don't see them, leaving only the correct matching string result.

The `data variable` gives a list of items:

```
<div id="#datafetch">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h2>
        <a>Lorem</a>
      </h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>
        <a>Ipsum</a>
      </h2>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>
        <a>Dolor</a>
      </h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I even tried:

```
if ($thisText !== text2B.trim()) {
        jQuery(".jumbotron").hide();
        $this.parent().parent().remove();
        jQuery("#componi").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled").show();
      } else {
        jQuery(".jumbotron").show();
  }
```

Comment: What's in the `data` variable?

Comment: In your code .jumbotron is removed when at least one string does not match, so of course it is removed always in your example.

Comment: Yes, but even if there is a match and show() is called, then the next comparison will call hide() (unless the last compared string is correct).

Comment: @endrju oh actually you are right!

Comment: @endrju I'm stuggling with the logic, I am trying to add a class to it to check if should be hidden or not but i can't get it to work. Could you help?

Comment: Try calling hide() before/outside each() loop and then show() if string matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a login flaw in this code. Jumbotron gets removed always because single mismatch (on any string) removes it.

In the updated code (with hide() and show()) there is a similar problem. Even if match occurs and the jumbotron is shown, then the next comparison hides it again.

The solution is to first (before each() loop) hide the jumbotron and show it only when match occurs.